# How to fetch a substring from text file in python?

Tags: python, string, text

I have a bunch of tweets in plaintext form that is shown below. I am looking to extract the **text part** only.

**SAMPLE DATA IN FILE** -

```
Fri Nov 13 20:27:16 +0000 2015 4181010297 rt     we're treating one of you lads to this d'struct denim shirt! simply follow &amp; rt to enter
Fri Nov 13 20:27:16 +0000 2015 2891325562 this album is wonderful, i'm so proud of you, i loved this album, it really is the best.    -273
Fri Nov 13 20:27:19 +0000 2015 2347993701 international break is garbage smh. it's boring and your players get injured
Fri Nov 13 20:27:20 +0000 2015 3168571911 get weather updates from the weather channel. 15:27:19
Fri Nov 13 20:27:20 +0000 2015 2495101558 woah what happened to twitter this update is horrible
Fri Nov 13 20:27:19 +0000 2015 229544082 i've completed the daily quest in paradise island 2!
Fri Nov 13 20:27:17 +0000 2015 309233999 new post: henderson memorial public library
Fri Nov 13 20:27:21 +0000 2015 291806707 who's going to  next week?
Fri Nov 13 20:27:19 +0000 2015 3031745900 why so blue?    @ golden bee
```

This is **my attempt** at the preprocess stage -

```
for filename in glob.glob('*.txt'):
    with open("plain text - preprocesshurricane.txt",'a') as outfile ,open(filename, 'r') as infile:
        for tweet in infile.readlines():
            temp=tweet.split(' ')
            text=""
            for i in temp:
                x=str(i)
                if x.isalpha() :
                    text += x + ' '
            print(text)
```

**OUTPUT-**

```
Fri Nov rt treating one of you lads to this denim simply follow rt to 
Fri Nov this album is so proud of i loved this it really is the 
Fri Nov international break is garbage boring and your players get 
Fri Nov get weather updates from the weather 
Fri Nov woah what happened to twitter this update is 
Fri Nov completed the daily quest in paradise island 
Fri Nov new henderson memorial public 
Fri Nov going to next 
Fri Nov why so golden
```

This output is **not the desired  output** because

*1. It will not let me fetch numbers/digits within the text part of the tweet.

2. Every line starts with FRI NOV.*

Could you please suggest a better method to achieve the same? I am not too familiar with regex, but I assume we could employ `re.search(r'2015(magic to remove tweetID)/w*',tweet)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can avoid regular expressions in this case. The lines of the text you've presented are consistent in terms of how many spaces go before the tweet text. Just [`split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
>>> data = """
   lines with tweets here
"""
>>> for line in data.splitlines():
...     print(line.split(" ", 7)[-1])
... 
rt     we're treating one of you lads to this d'struct denim shirt! simply follow &amp; rt to enter
this album is wonderful, i'm so proud of you, i loved this album, it really is the best.    -273
international break is garbage smh. it's boring and your players get injured
get weather updates from the weather channel. 15:27:19
woah what happened to twitter this update is horrible
i've completed the daily quest in paradise island 2!
new post: henderson memorial public library
who's going to  next week?
why so blue?    @ golden bee
```

Comment: What is that [-1] doing ? Setting the index to just before the space?

Comment: @MayurH `line.split(" ", 7)` splits a line by  the first 7 spaces. It produces a list in which the tweet text is the last item - we get it by the last index.

Comment: @MayurH The index `-1` in `<any-list>[-1]` points to the last position in `<any-list>` (gives IndexError on an empty list). You can do fancy stuff like `<some-list>[-3:]` to get a list of the last three elements etc..

Comment: I didn't know that  line.split() could take more than one argument. Thanks! I forgot that it returns a list. It makes sense now.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it without a regular expression

```
import glob

for filename in glob.glob('file.txt'):
    with open("plain text - preprocesshurricane.txt",'a') as outfile ,open(filename, 'r') as infile:
        for tweet in infile.readlines():
            temp=tweet.split(' ')
            print('{}'.format(' '.join(temp[7:])))
```

Comment: This again is undesired output I believe. This includes FRI NOV? But I realise now that I simply had to break the split and join after the 7th space. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I propose a little more specific pattern than @Rushy Panchal to avoid issues when tweets include digits: `.+ \+(\d+ ){3}`

**Use re.sub function**

```
>>> import re
>>> with open('your_file.txt','r') as file:
...     data = file.read()
...     print re.sub('.+ \+(\d+ ){3}','',data)
```

**Output**

```
rt     we're treating one of you lads to this d'struct denim shirt! simply follow &amp; rt to enter
this album is wonderful, i'm so proud of you, i loved this album, it really is the best.    -273
international break is garbage smh. it's boring and your players get injured
get weather updates from the weather channel. 15:27:19
woah what happened to twitter this update is horrible
i've completed the daily quest in paradise island 2!
new post: henderson memorial public library
who's going to  next week?
why so blue?    @ golden bee
```

Answer (score 0):

The pattern you are looking for is `.+ \d+`:

```
import re
p = re.compile(".+ \d+")
tweets = p.sub('', data) # data is the original string
```

**Breakdown of the Pattern**

`.` matches any character, and `+` matches 1 or more. So, `.+` matches one or more characters. However, if we left it at just this, we would remove all of the text.

So, we want to end the pattern with `\d+` – `\d` matches any digit, and so this would match any continuous sequence of digits, the last of which are the tweet IDs.

Comment: Will check this and revert to you.

Comment: Your pattern doesn't work for this line: `Fri Nov 13 20:27:20 +0000 2015 3168571911 get weather updates from the weather channel. 15:27:19`. You display `:27:19`.